# JSONTypeInfo to not ignore property in inheritance mapping

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jsonserializer

I am using following dependency for JSON serialization/deserialization

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I have inheritance mapping.

Following is `Parent` class.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "isOne")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = One.class, name = "true"), @Type(value = Two.class, name = "false") })
public class Parent extends AbstractValueObject {
     private Boolean isOne;
}
```

And we have two sub class `One` and `Two` extended by `Parent`.

This mapping is working when I serialize/deserialize with the help of property `isOne`.

But the **problem** is when JSON is converted to class jackson *removes the property `isOne`*. Is there any way which does not remove that property. It don't recommend any dummy property as long as i can have actual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc for [JsonTypeInfo](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html?is-external=true) you can use `visible=true`

Try this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "isOne", visible = true)
```